# Perl - Is this a bug with looks_like_number, or am I being a stupid person?

Tags: perl

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

sub what_the_fudge {
    my $string = "foo 123 bar";
    if ($string =~ /foo (.+) bar/) {
        if (looks_like_number($1)) {
            print "$1 looks like a number\n";
        } else {
            print "$1 doesnt look like a number\n";
        }
    }
}

&what_the_fudge;
&what_the_fudge;
&what_the_fudge;
```

Displays this:

```
123 doesnt look like a number
123 looks like a number
123 looks like a number
```

Why does it fail to recognize it as a number the first time? =(
This baffles me.

Some information about my environment:

OS: OSX 10.6.8

`perl -e 'use Scalar::Util; print "$Scalar::Util::VERSION\n"'`
--> 1.19

`perl -v`
--> This is perl, v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level (with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: Cannot replicate, I get correct result all three times.

Comment: You might consider renaming your sub's name for the sake of SO.

Comment: Also cannot replicate.

Comment: Multiple CNR (cannot reproduce) reports — which version of Perl are you using, and which platform are you using it on?

Comment: And please show the output of `perl -e 'use Scalar::Util; print "$Scalar::Util::VERSION\n"'`

Comment: I called the function 100 times, twice, and I cannot reproduce your issue. Sorry I've tried my best :(

Comment: I ran the code too, cannot reproduce (Perl 5.8.8, scalar util version 1.21)

Comment: Hi guys. `perl -e 'use Scalar::Util; print "$Scalar::Util::VERSION\n"'` reports that I have version 1.19. I am using the version of Perl that is loaded with Snow Leopard (OSX 10.6.8). `perl -v` reports that `This is perl, v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)`

Comment: Also, interestingly, I can fix the code by changing `if (looks_like_number($1))` to `$temp = $1; if (looks_like_number($temp))`. Pretty stupid. =(

Comment: You're probably using the Pure Perl version of Scalar::Util, which probably uses a regex, which clobbers `$1`. `looks_like_number("$1")` will fix it.

Comment: @ikegami, I don't think that's it.  The first thing `l_l_a_number()` does is `local $_ = shift`, making a *copy* of the OP's `$1` in this case.  In any case I cannot reproduce with 5.10.1 (or any perl) and the S:U:PP 1.19 implementation.

Comment: @On a Mac running OS X 10.8.6 with various versions of Perlbrew (and default 5.12 installed). When I use 5.8.9 or 5.10.1, I see the error. Use my native 5.12.4 and it's not there. Use Perlbrew 5.16 or 5.18, and no problem.

Comment: +1: This is a very interesting problem. At least OP should get some credit for that,

Comment: @ikegami I can verify it's not a Pure Perl issue (although Pure Perl does use regexp). I'm running the XS code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug that was fixed in Scalar::Util 1.20. ("Handle overloaded and tied values" in the `Changes` file.)

The XS version of `looks_like_number` failed to handle magical arguments properly. Magic is what allows code to be called when certain operations are performed on a variable (such as fetching its value).

Solutions:

- Upgrade to Scalar::Util 1.20 or higher.
- Delete the compiled component of your Scalar::Util to force the use of the Pure Perl implementation which doesn't suffer from this problem.
- Use `looks_like_number("$1")` which creates a non-magical copy of `$1` with the right value.

---

1.19:

```
int
looks_like_number(sv)
        SV *sv
PROTOTYPE: $
CODE:
#if (PERL_VERSION < 8) || (PERL_VERSION == 8 && PERL_SUBVERSION <5)
  if (SvPOK(sv) || SvPOKp(sv)) {
    RETVAL = looks_like_number(sv);
  }
  else {
    RETVAL = SvFLAGS(sv) & (SVf_NOK|SVp_NOK|SVf_IOK|SVp_IOK);
  }
#else
  RETVAL = looks_like_number(sv);
#endif
OUTPUT:
 RETVAL
```

1.21:

```
int
looks_like_number(sv)
    SV *sv
PROTOTYPE: $
CODE:
  SV *tempsv;
  if (SvAMAGIC(sv) && (tempsv = AMG_CALLun(sv, numer))) {
    sv = tempsv;
  }
  else if (SvMAGICAL(sv)) {
      SvGETMAGIC(sv);
  }
#if (PERL_VERSION < 8) || (PERL_VERSION == 8 && PERL_SUBVERSION <5)
  if (SvPOK(sv) || SvPOKp(sv)) {
    RETVAL = looks_like_number(sv);
  }
  else {
    RETVAL = SvFLAGS(sv) & (SVf_NOK|SVp_NOK|SVf_IOK|SVp_IOK);
  }
#else
  RETVAL = looks_like_number(sv);
#endif
OUTPUT:
  RETVAL
```

---

Try this:

```
what_the_fudge("foo 123 bar");
what_the_fudge("foo baz bar");
what_the_fudge("foo 123 bar");

sub what_the_fudge {
    my $string = shift;
```

I haven't actually tried it, but you should get

```
Version of Scalar::Util: 1.19
doesnt look like a number
looks like a number
doesnt look like a number
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a few modifications in your program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

print "Scalar version: $Scalar::Util::VERSION\n";
what_the_fudge();
what_the_fudge();
what_the_fudge();

sub what_the_fudge {
    my $string = "foo 123 bar";
    if ($string =~ /foo (.+) bar/) {
        if ( looks_like_number $1 ) {
            print qq("$1" looks like a number\n);
        } else {
            print qq("$1" doesn't look like a number\n);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a Mac running 10.8.6, and I use Perlbrew to test 5.8.9, 5.10, 5.12, and 5.18. With the first two I get this:

```
Scalar version: 1.19
"123" doesnt look like a number
"123" looks like a number
"123" looks like a number
```

With the other two versions, I get this:

```
Scalar version: 1.22
"123" looks like a number
"123" looks like a number
"123" looks like a number
```

I then made another slight change in your program. Instead of simply using `$1`, I set `my $test = $1`, then ran `looks_like_number( $test )`;

After doing that, I got this:

```
Scalar version: 1.19
"123" looks like a number
"123" looks like a number
"123" looks like a number
```

One of the things you must understand is that `$1`, `$_`, and their ilk aren't just global variables, but always in the `main` namespace. This means that if you call a subroutine using `$1`, it is possible that the subroutine could end up munging the value.

You should always assign your own variables (and preferably `my` variables) instead of relying on special Perl variables. This means not using `$_` in `while` and `for` loops, and not manipulating `@_` directly in subroutines. And, when you use regular expression capturing, you should assign your own variables to `$1`, `$2`, etc. as soon as you can.

By the way, the most interesting difference between version 1.22 and 1.19 of Scalar::Util is that version 1.22 will use the C compiled code if it exists. If not, it loads Scalar::Util::PP which is the Perl version. However, when I used `Scalar::Util::PP` in Perl 5.12 and 5.18, I still get the correct output.

### Curiouser and Curiouser

I tried modifying `Scalar::Util` to see what is going on. However, I see:

```
require List::Util; # List::Util loads the XS
```

And the Perl version of the code is encased in a big Eval statement. It is interesting that the side effect is only caught in the first one -- although the subroutine is setting the string, and running the regex.  Same code, but executes two different ways.

Adding quotes around `$1` makes it behave the right way:

```
if ( looks_like_number "$1" ) {
```

Also simply printing it out makes it work:

```
print "The value is " . $1 . "\n";
if ( looks_like_number $1 ) {
```

Or assigning it to another variable, but not using that variable:

```
my $test = $1;
if ( looks_like_number $1 ) {   works now...
```

Let's use the debugger and see if we can trace the problem:

```
$ perl -d test.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.31
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(test.pl:7):  print "Version of Scalar::Util: $Scalar::Util::VERSION\n";
  DB<1> c
Version of Scalar::Util: 1.19
"123" looks like a number.
"123" looks like a number.
"123" looks like a number.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
```

It works? Let's try the same command without the `-d` parameter:

```
$ perl test.pl
Version of Scalar::Util: 1.19
"123" doesn't look like a number.
"123" looks like a number.
"123" looks like a number.
```

How can you trace down this problem if you can't get see it in the debugger?

Comment: *"[a] subroutine [called using $1] could end up munging [$1]"*  Well, yes, but only within the sub itself.  Since at least 5.8.8, `$1` is automatically and helpfully dynamically scoped (er, dynamically localized), so the caller of that subroutine won't notice any changes to `$1` once it returns.

Comment: @pilcrow The strangeness is that the same code is executing three times, but the first one returns a different result.

Comment: @David W., See my answer. Use Devel::Peek's `Dump` and look at the `PV` before and after the call to `looks_like_number`. You'll see it unchanged, which it should have been updated by `mg_get`. It works later because of the string concat

Answer (score 2):

According to ikegami,

> You're probably using the Pure Perl version of Scalar::Util, which
>   probably uses a regex, which clobbers $1. looks_like_number("$1") will
>   fix it.

Thanks! This fixed it.

Comment: As @pilcrow pointed out, my guess of the reason appears to be wrong. My new guess is that there is a bug in that version of Perl that's causing `$1`'s magic to not be called. The solution is the same because the stringification of `$1` (`looks_like_number("$1")`) does call its magic.

Comment: It's not the Pure Perl version. I have the same issue on my machine using Perlbrew, and I can verify that the Pure Perl version isn't being loaded. Using the debugger _fixes_ the problem too.